# Calculate $\lvert A \rvert$ if $a_{ij}=0$ if $i=j$ and $1$ otherwise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $A=[a_{ij}] \in M_{n\times n} (R)$ be the matrix defined by

$a_{ij}=0$  if $i=j$
    $1$ otherwise

To be honest, I've only calculated determinants of matrices with numbers, nothing like this.

Comment: correction made

Comment: And now the title is also fixed.

Comment: Did you try it with $n=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: This is a rank 1 perturbation of a diagonal matrix, so look at this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730134/determinant-of-rank-one-perturbation-of-a-diagonal-matrix

Comment: @JonasMeyer no, I did not. I wasnt sure what to do at first.

Comment: I suggest, when you don't know what to do at first, try something simple to get started. In this case, starting with $n=1$, then $n=2$, etc., may help.

Answer (score 10):

Add all the columns to the first one and then subtract the first row from the others we find

$$\left|\begin{array}\\
n-1&1&\cdots&1\\
0&-1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\cdots&-1&0\\
0&\cdots&&-1
\end{array}\right|=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$$

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use the fact that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.
Let $B$ be the matrix with ones everywhere. Then $A=B-I$ it is easy to see that the eigenvalues of $B$ are $n$ with multiplicity $1$ and $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$.
Now if $(B-I)v=\lambda v$ then  $Bv=(\lambda +1)v$ so the eigenvalues of $B$ are 
$n-1$ with multiplicity $1$ and $-1$ with multiplicity $n-1$. This gives $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$ in agreement with the answer of Sami.

Comment: We posted very near answers at nearly the same time.  I deleted mine.

Comment: I noticed that. There was no need to delete it, it would have been upvoted.

Comment: I agree it is not needed, but I think it is more useful deleted.

Comment: I think that often times different verbalizations of the same result, proof, solution, etc., will appeal to, or be clear to, different readers.  So I don't mind multiple expressions of the same line of thought.  You never know what will "hit" a given reader.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis, I agree. I have looked at different solutions to the same problem and found myself confused with some approaches but clearer with others.