# Cute problem: determinant of $I_n+(f_if_j)_{i,j}$

Tags: matrices

I thought of the following little problem.

Given numbers $f_1,\dots f_n$, what is the determinant of the symmetric matrix $I_n+(f_if_j)_{i,j}$?

I have found a cute combinatorial-style proof that it is $1+\Sigma_i f_i^2$. using the sum over permutations formula for the determinant. Here $F(\sigma)$ denotes the set of fixed points of $\sigma$.

[image]
Does anyone have a faster/more elegant method?

Comment: Some solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101657/find-the-determinant-of-the-following-matrix and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730134/determinant-of-rank-one-perturbation-of-a-diagonal-matrix. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420198/42969.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $(f_if_j)$ are $(\|f\|^2, 0,\dots,0)$ so those of your matrix are $(1+\|f\|^2, 1,\dots,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Overkill but Sylvester's Theorem tells us:
$$\det(I_n + XY) = \det(I_m+YX)$$
for $X, Y$ of sizes of $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ respectively. Then for $F = (f_1,f_2,\dots f_n):$
$$\det(I_n + F^TF) = \det(I_1+FF^T) = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2$$

Comment: @BenjaminWang yes